# java main and child threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I've been doing a bit of research into threads and it seems im lost. I am wondering what are main and child threads. How are they made? and what is the difference between them.

Answer (score 3):

The "main" thread is created for you and it calls `public static void main(String[] args)`

The "child" threads are those you create yourself from main or from another of your threads.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new thread from the current thread then the current thread will be the `parent thread` and the new threads will be `child thread`.

The main class that runs first is called the `main thread`. The main thread will typically be parent thread for all threads for the application.